# get_item_album_art_uri returns None

Tags: python, sonos

I am working with the Sonos Library, soco

it has a method for retrieving album art, for current played artist.
It returns None every time. Just dont get it.

```
def artImage(self):
    currentZone = str(self.cb.currentText())
    deviceDict= self.sonosZonesCoordinatorsIP()
    for key, value in deviceDict.items():
        if value == currentZone:
            device = SoCo(key)
            track = device.get_current_track_info()
            current_album = track["album"]
            album_art_uri  = device.get_item_album_art_uri(current_album)
```

Below a snippet from soco module:

```
def get_item_album_art_uri(self, item):
    """Get an item's Album Art absolute URI."""

    if getattr(item, 'album_art_uri', False):
        return self._build_album_art_full_uri(item.album_art_uri)
    else:
        return None
```

and a link to it: https://github.com/SoCo/SoCo/blob/master/soco/core.py

In advance, many thanks.
Just tired of not figuring this out....

Comment: Not familiar with SoCo, but is the attribute `album_art_uri` present in the dictionary `current_album` ? What does the data look like in `track`?

Comment: track is a dict, holding information of currently played song fx: {u'album': 'Memories...Do Not Open', u'artist': 'The Chainsmokers', u'title': 'Break Up Every Night', u'uri': 'x-sonos-spotify:spotify%3atrack%3a6cPyTS0Kk2sc4xQwC93kOg?'}

So, no it is not....I guess that would be the issue ?

Comment: Well, you're trying to get an attribute that doesn't exist in your data.Thats why your `get_item_album_art` method returns None because the getattr returns False. You probably need to find another way to get more info about the track using Soco.

Comment: you are right, its called : u'album_art': u'http://192.168.1.112:1400/getaa?s=1&u=x-sonos-spotify%3aspotify%253atrack%253a3rOSwuTsUlJp0Pu0MkN8r8%3fsid%3d9%26flags%3d8224%26sn%3d2',

thank you both for pointing me in the direction. the method was updated with a new attributename....

Comment: What if you pass the `track` dict to the method `get_item_album_art_uri`?

Comment: ok! just noticed your new comment